# Setting POST data's encoding on WPF WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, http

**Backgrounds**

I've been using my own site to send a POST request to another site that requires a specific sender url, which is my site's url. And now I'm trying to send the automated POST request with my WPF application. I can't use httpclient's sendAsync function because that way I can't include valid site url for header. Therefore I'm trying to send the request from WebBrowser by loading the page and filling the input values, and then submitting the form. And here's my problem.

**Problem**

This target server that receives POST request requires a specific encoding, something other than UTF-8. And my site is configured to fit that encoding and works fine on the actual web browsers like chrome or IE. But when I send the exact same request from the WPF WebBrowser by loading the same page, somehow the encoding goes wrong. I'd like my WPF WebBrowser to send the POST request under specific encoding, but I can't find the way to do so. I'd be graceful for any advice. Thank you in advance.

**What I've tried**

I've inserted `<meta encoding="~">`to my html, also set `<form charset="~">` on the form. But it still sends the invalid encoding request.

Comment: I've tried to include all the information I suspect to be related, but if there's any additional information I can include to help solving this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into my request's broken text and ran it through decoder which restores broken text into original one, so I could be confident that my request in WPF was encoded with UTF-8. Then I could find a `WebBrowser.Document.encoding` option. My `defaultEncoding` was set to UTF-8 and it caused all the problems. By fixing it to `document.encoding = "myEncoding";`, my problem was solved.